# Why can't I see my friends posts in this Facebook list?

Tags: facebook, list

I have a list on Facebook with friends in it. it says `4` new posts when I log-in but when I click on it it says "There are no posts to show" (but in Swedish). What can I do about this?

On other lists I just see some posts. Why is Facebook only showing me "some" posts? 
The only reason I have the lists is so I can choose when to read there posts.

Here's an example of the "bug" I have.

[image]

[image]

Sorry for the swedish. (oops) In the bottom line it says "There are no more posts to show right now"

Vipan is the list of some schoolmates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be a bug and you just need to send a screenshot and report it.

On the other hand it could be that you reviewed these posts in the news feed (at least this is how it appeared to me when this situation occurred)

I just added some friends to a new list to see if I can replicate again. I will let you know how it goes in a few days.

Comment: a screenshot of what exactly?

Comment: `it says 4 new posts when I log-in but when I click on it it says "There are no posts to show"` @Alvar

Comment: the friends I can't see doesn't appear in my news feed since I only want the people I talk to on a regular basis there. could this be the "bug"?

Comment: I  reported it as a bug, and a week ago it got fixed! It's now working perfectly! :) thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well, this happened to me, but I got a solution:

1. write a post ex. "Boredooooooooom"
2. then click the sort button where it says "There are no more posts to show right now"
3. tick the "Top Stories" button and now the posts should be there ;)